# Django query to find all items without a FK relationship except for excluded list

Tags: python, performance, database, django

I have a `Book` model and an `Author` model that has a FK relationship to `Book` (I realize that it should be the other way around, but I had to change the names of the real items to Book and Author for proprietary reasons.)  Related name on this relationship is `authors`.

I am trying to find all Books that do not have an Author or Authors, except for an exclude list of tuples called `BOOKS_WITH_NO_AUTHORS` that is about 25 items long and unlikely to grow much.  The pair of items in the tuples are unique together.  I can change this list of tuples to a dictionary or other format if that is helpful.

Everything works but it is very slow.  The database of books and authors is large.

```
BOOKS_WITH_NO_AUTHORS = [(1979, "ABC123"), (1928, "DEF456")]  

def missing_author(request):

    excluded_books = [Book.objects.get(publish_year=book[0], book_num=book[1]).book_id
                      for book in BOOKS_WITH_NO_AUTHORS]

    books_missing_authors = Book.objects. \
        filter(authors=None). \
        exclude(book_id__in=excluded_books). \
        order_by('publish_year')

    return render(request,
                  'missing_author.html',
                  {"data": books_missing_authors})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the inefficiencies in your code is when you're  collecting the list of ids of excluded_books. If you have 25 `BOOKS_WITH_NO_AUTHORS`, you're hitting the database 25 times.

I would recommend using the `Q` objects.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

This should substantially speed it up:

```
from django.db.models import Q


BOOKS_WITH_NO_AUTHORS = [(1979, "ABC123"), (1928, "DEF456")]

def missing_author(request):

    # Turn list of BOOKS_WITH_NO_AUTHORS into list of Q objects
    queries = [Q(publish_year=publish_year, book_num=book_num) for publish_year, book_num in BOOKS_WITH_NO_AUTHORS]

    # Take one Q object from the list
    query = queries.pop()

    # Or the Q object with the ones remaining in the list
    for item in queries:
        query |= item

    books_missing_authors = Book.objects. \
        filter(authors=None). \
        exclude(query). \
        order_by('publish_year')

    return render(request,
                  'missing_author.html',
                  {"data": books_missing_authors})
```

Comment: Still slow, but faster!  Thanks!

Comment: Slow? Add index on `publish_year, book_num`